# Bonus which will have to be paid back

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, california

I received a retention bonus during the tax year 18, with the clause that if I leave within the year I have to pay back the full amount. I will hand in my resignation and will have to pay back bonus prior to tax day. After that I will leave the country and as such have to file a partial tax return. For both years I'm not a citizen but a residence for tax purposes (already filled for a few years).

I plan to hand in both my partial 19 and full 18 tax return at the same time. How would I handle the bonus received in 18 and returned in 19?

I'm not sure [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/reporting-sign-on-bonus-in-case-i-need-to-return) answers my case, as I'm asking for a partial tax return (19) and I already will have payed back the amount once I hand in the 18 return. The amount is over $3k.

Comment: The linked question answers it pretty well, the partial tax year has no bearing on the handling of the bonus payback. Further reading: https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2613585-i-was-paid-a-signing-bonus-in-2014-and-repaid-it-in-2015-how-does-this-effect-my-2014-tax-year  and https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p525.pdf